# Android Xamarin TreeView nLevels

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I spent so much time for discover how to implement TreeView in Android Xamarin, but unlucky seem not have any example say about that.

I tried to use **ExpandableListView** but it only support to level 2 category. I need someone will have any guide to through this content or some example say about that.

*The purpose is explore the folders on server!*

Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The purpose is explore the folders on server!

You can use [Binding Library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/) to import some java library for example like [AndroidTreeView](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView).

For example, I created an .aar lib from this project. And then code for example like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    //create root
    TreeNode root = TreeNode.InvokeRoot();
    TreeNode parent = new TreeNode("parent");
    TreeNode child0 = new TreeNode("ChildNode0");
    TreeNode child1 = new TreeNode("ChildNode1");

    TreeItem item = new TreeItem() { text = "abc" };
    TreeNode child10 = new TreeNode(item).SetViewHolder(new MyHolder(this));
    child1.AddChild(child10);
    parent.AddChildren(child0, child1);
    root.AddChild(parent);

    AndroidTreeView atv = new AndroidTreeView(this, root);

    LinearLayout rootlayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.rootlayout);
    rootlayout.AddView(atv.View);

    rootlayout.Invalidate();
}
```

The `TreeItem` is created like this:

```
public class TreeItem : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public string text;
}
```

And `MyHolder` is like this:

```
public class MyHolder : TreeNode.BaseNodeViewHolder
{
    private Context mcontext;

    public MyHolder(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        mcontext = context;
    }

    public override View CreateNodeView(TreeNode p0, Java.Lang.Object p1)
    {
        var inflater = LayoutInflater.FromContext(mcontext);
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.itemview, null, false);
        TextView tv = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.itemtv);
        var item = p1 as TreeItem;
        tv.Text = item.text;
        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is the [demo](https://github.com/GraceFeng/XamarinTreeView), you can find the [.aar lib](https://github.com/GraceFeng/XamarinTreeView/tree/master/TreeViewLib/Jars) there.

Comment: Why can you have a great answer like that!