# EventHandling in TreeView (Xamarin android)

Tags: xamarin.android, treeview, treenode

I have developed a treeview in xamarin android.I followed this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071583/android-xamarin-treeview-nlevels) to develop the below sample.

In MyHolder.cs there is a method called CreateNodeView() which is displaying all the nodes. 
Here when I am clicking on the ParentNode the control is going to ParentView_Click()[Event Handler].
The problem that I am facing is after returning from ParentView_Click() the levels which are below ParentNode are not displaying.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**MyHolder.cs:**

```
namespace XamarinTreeView
{
public class MyHolder : TreeNode.BaseNodeViewHolder
{

    private Context mcontext;
    TextView level2_View, child_View, parent_View;

    public MyHolder(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        mcontext = context;
    }

    public override View CreateNodeView(TreeNode p0, Java.Lang.Object p1)
    {
        var inflater = LayoutInflater.FromContext(mcontext);
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.itemview, null, true);

        level2_View = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.itemtv);
        child_View = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.itemtv1);
        parent_View = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.parent_tv);
        // tv.Click += Tv_Click;


        var item = p1 as TreeItem;
        if (item.text == " ParentNode" || item.text == " Child1")
        {
            var view2 = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.parentview, null, true);
            parent_View = view2.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.parent_tv);
            parent_View.Text = item.text;
            parent_View.Click += ParentView_Click;             
            return view2;
        }
        if (item.text == " Level3-1" || item.text == " Level3-2" || item.text == " Level4")
        {
            var view1 = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.childview, null, true);
            child_View = view1.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.itemtv1);
            child_View.Text = item.text;
            return view1;
        }
        else
        {
            level2_View.Text = item.text;
            return view;
        }
    }

    private void ParentView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int iLeft = Resource.Drawable.plus;
        parent_View.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(iLeft, 0, 0, 0);
    }      
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a click event on the `Node`, you can use `TreeNode.setClickListener(TreeNodeClickListener listener);`.

Implement the `TreeNode.ITreeNodeClickListener` for you `MainActivity`:

```
 public void OnClick(TreeNode p0, Object p1)
        {
            //do something
        var view = parent.ViewHolder.View as View;
        int iLeft = Resource.Drawable.dapao;
        TextView tv = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.itemtv);
        tv.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(iLeft, 0, 0, 0);
        tv.Text = "adfasdf";
        Toast.MakeText(this, "111", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
```

In the `OnCreate` method add the listener:

```
parent.SetClickListener(this);
```

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView/blob/d051ce75f5c9bd5206481808f6133b51f581c8f1/README.md).

And I also provide a demo on [github](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/TreeViewTest)

Comment: Thanks.. Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Glad it helped :).